# Work done by a moving normal force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy-conservation

Say someone climbs up a downward moving escalator. He climbs up with 1.5 the speed relative to the escalator. How would you go about calculating the work done by the someone? If it was a still staircase, then the work done would just be mgh. But since the escalator is moving there's likely something else I have to account for right? To generalise, I'm curious how you calculate the work done by a body (the someone climbing up), if the object (escalator) that the work is done on is moving?

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the work done by a person (or a $100\%$ efficient machine) climbing a moving escalator, replace $mgh$ by $mgh'$ where $h'$ is the vertical distance that they have climbed *relative to the escalator*. If the person is climbing with a speed that is $1.5$ times that of the escalator then in the time they climb a vertical distance $h$ relative to the ground, the escalator has moved a vertical distance $-2h$ relative to the ground, so the vertical distance that the person has climbed relative to the escalator is $3h$, and the work they have done is $mgh' = 3mgh$.

These calculations assume that the person starts and ends with the same velocity and is $100\%$ efficient and no energy is lost to the environment as heat, sound etc. This is, of course, unrealistic.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest formula to use is typically $$P=\vec F \cdot \vec v$$ where $P$ (power) is the rate of work done by force $\vec F$ acting on the system at a point where the material of the system is moving with velocity $\vec v$.

Assuming that the persons feet are not slipping on the escalator then the $\vec v$ is the velocity of the escalator. And assuming that the person is walking at a steady pace then the person’s acceleration is zero so the force is $-m\vec g$.

Calculate the power then integrate over time to get the work. Note that this will be less than the change in gravitational energy. This value will be the work done by the escalator. The remaining is the amount of internal energy converted to gravitational energy within the person.